# Unable to Input list variable values in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to create CosmosDB with Terraform and using list variable type for subnet as we have multiple subnet within a VNET. But I'm getting below error -

var.subnet is list of string with 2 elements

│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

My variable.tf and main.tf are here-

```
# ================
# Variable.tf
# ==============
variable "vnet" {
  description = "Provide VNET Name"
  default     = "cosmosdb-icn-vnet"
}

variable "subnet" {
  description = "Specifies subnet name"
  type        = list(string)
}

# ====================
# main.tf
# ===================
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                              = "cosmosdb-${var.environment}"
  location                          = var.location
  resource_group_name               = var.rgname
  offer_type                        = "Standard"
  enable_automatic_failover         = true
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = true
 
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }

  tags = {
    ENVIRONMENT = var.environment
  }

  backup {
    type                = var.backuptype
    interval_in_minutes = "60"
    retention_in_hours  = "8"
  }

  virtual_network_rule {
    id                                   = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription}/resourceGroups/${var.rgname}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/${var.vnet}/subnets/${var.subnet}"
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true

  }

  geo_location {
    location          = var.failover_location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

}
```

And I'm using below command for apply

`terraform apply -var='subnet=["deafult", "cosmosdb2.0"]'`

Comment: Your `var.subnet` used within a string, so you cannot input a list but must input a string. What exactly are you trying to obtain?

Comment: Hi @LazyEval - I'm trying to create CosmosDB and passing Subnet and vnet. I tried to pass subnet in different ways also but did not work. So using this way.

Comment: Hi @LazyEval - We have multiple subnet within VNET so passing single string won't work here. I need to pass a list so please help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try separating the two subnets and therefore creating two `virtual_network_rule` blocks in the resource:

```
# ================
# Variable.tf
# ==============
variable "vnet" {
  description = "Provide VNET Name"
  default     = "cosmosdb-icn-vnet"
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "Specifies subnet names"
  type        = list(string)
}

# ====================
# main.tf
# ===================
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                              = "cosmosdb-${var.environment}"
  location                          = var.location
  resource_group_name               = var.rgname
  offer_type                        = "Standard"
  enable_automatic_failover         = true
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = true
 
  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Session"
  }

  tags = {
    ENVIRONMENT = var.environment
  }

  backup {
    type                = var.backuptype
    interval_in_minutes = "60"
    retention_in_hours  = "8"
  }

  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
  for_each = var.subnets
    id                                   = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription}/resourceGroups/${var.rgname}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/${var.vnet}/subnets/${virtual_network_rule.value}"
    ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = var.failover_location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @LazyEval - Thanks for the help. But this won't work because for testing i took two subnets but we have more than 5-6 subnets. so creating 5-6 variable wont be a good practice. Can you please me any other approach please.

Comment: made the EDIT creating a dynamic block. Try it out

Comment: when I try following on azurerm_cosmosdb_account                                           backup {  type = "Periodic" interval_in_minutes = "80" } . I am getting error as "Blocks of type backup are not expected here. Has anyone seen this error

Comment: have you tried running `terraform fmt` before `terraform plan/apply`? You have to make sure the format is correct